# How can I transfer a C console application to work as a native iOS plugin with unity?

Tags: ios, c, unity-game-engine, midi, coremidi

I am trying to get MIDI input for my unity project (for IOS). Since there is no direct support for MIDI I am trying to write a native plugin myself.

I got a C console application working using CoreMidi API, but now I have no idea how to connect it with unity, since all the examples I can find for doing native iOS plugins for unity are using Objective C.

Maybe anybody can help me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a tutorial about this which could be a good start: http://unreferencedinstance.com/tutorial_cpp_unity3d/

In short:
You need to define your methods as `extern`, tell complier to make them available from 'the outside' and call them in Unity like this:

```
[DllImport ("LowLevelPlugin")]
private static extern int[,] fillArray(int size);
```